# How to format an enumerate differently only if it has a single item?

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I want to do an enumerate that is formatted in a way if it has multiple items, but in a different way if it has a single item. Something like this:

A list with multiple items:

```
#1 Item1
#2 Item2
#3 Item3
```

A list with a single item:

```
* SingleItem
```

I'm currently using `enumitem` package to format my lists, so it would be nice to use it, but any other solution would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am struggling with my pupils saying them that a list with just **one** item should not be formatted as a list.

Comment: Do you know in advance, how many items the `enumeration` will have?

Comment: Well, I could count or even force a different format for a single item, but I'm looking for something more scalable and elegant. :)

Comment: See my possible solution

Comment: I'd agree that a list with one item should not be a list... but the list may grow in later revisions and I'd not like to change the code structure when that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty trial solution, looping over a list using `etoolbox` macros and releasing it a specialized `enumerate` environment

Description:

`\IntelligentEnumerate` is a wrapper with three arguments:

1. The first is optional, containing the label and other setups for the enumerate optional argument
2. The first contains the list items as a comma-separated list (mandatory)
3. The 3rd one is optional again, containing the options for the single item 'list'

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\def\myitemlist{}

\newcounter{somecounter}

\newcommand{\additemtolist}[1]{%
\stepcounter{somecounter}%
\listgadd{\myitemlist}{#1}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\IntelligentEnumerate}{+O{label={\#\arabic*}}+m+O{label={\textasteriskcentered}}}{%
  \setcounter{somecounter}{0}
  \forcsvlist{\additemtolist}{#2}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{somecounter}}{1}{%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \item ##1
    }
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]
      \dolistloop{\myitemlist}
    \end{enumerate}
  }{%
    \begin{enumerate}[#3]
    \item  #2
    \end{enumerate}
  }%   
  \def\myitemlist{}% 'Clear' the list at the end 
}



\begin{document}

\IntelligentEnumerate{First, Second, Third}


\IntelligentEnumerate[label={\Roman*}]{First, Second, Third}


\IntelligentEnumerate{This is a single Item}

\IntelligentEnumerate{This is a single Item}[label={$\int$}]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to have `\par` like stuff, you have to hide the content in a macro and enter this macro in the csv - list